# Read only property in a required text field in Vaadin removes the asterisk (*)

Tags: java, vaadin

When you set a text field as required, an asterik (*) is shown at the end of the field caption. If I set a required field as read only, this asterisk disappears.

An asterisk is shown:

```
TextField tf = new TextField("My text field");
tf.setRequired(true);
```

The asterisk disappears:

```
TextField tf = new TextField("My text field");
tf.setRequired(true);
tf.setReadOnly(true);
```

Is there any way to avoid this and show the asterisk when the field is required and read only?

Comment: What is the use case of this, since the user can't do anything about it?

Comment: The user needs to now wich fields are required. If a text field is read only it means that he can't type a value (the value in inserted in the field in a different way). The problem is that if the asterisk dissapears, the user could think that the field is not required.

Answer (score 1):

A readonly field is meant to not be modified by the user, so the indicator is not displayed.

If you still wish to have it, then you can set the field to disabled, and the user can't enter a value, but the required indicator is still shown.

There exists a [wiki entry](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ReadOnly+vs.+Disabled+fields) when to use readonly versus disabled fields.